# macOS Mojave:Trying (and failing) to do manual mail migration

Tags: email, migration, macos-mojave

My Mac (MacBookPro 2012) was getting clunkier and clunkier. I backed the whole think up with Carbon Copy Cloner, and then did a clean Mojave install.

I tried the following:

- Renamed "Mail" folder in clean system Library.
- Copied "Mail" from old Library to clean (and fixed permissions)
- Moved "com.apple.mail.plist" from old Library/Preferences to clean (and
  fixed permissions)
- There was no file named "com.apple.mail.plist" in the clean Library/Preferences (but there is one named "com.apple.mail-shared.plist")
- Restart. Open mail and there are no mail-boxes. Basically dead.
- Go back to original (clean) files, and launch Mail. Get one iCloud account.

I have gigabytes of mail and multiple accounts I would like to move. I don't want to use migration assistant as it will bring all the dross with it.

Anyone out there know what I'm doing wrong??